# FingerPrint Scanner wont detect any input (fingerprint image)

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

Hi good day to all I have a project that , it will lock the solenoid using the fingerprint then I have hook up a coinslot that will count the coins inside the vault its like a secured piggybank.

Project objective

1. it must display the coin total :
2. If fingerprint is access it will unlock the solenoid
3. then goes back to total of coins

The problem is its just showing total of coins inserte but the fingerprint wont detect any image id taken from enrrol code

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>    //Libraries needed
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#include <EEPROM.h>
#define coinSlot 9 // different pin!!! untested!!!

#define I2C_ADDR 0x27          //LCD i2c stuff
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN 3
#define En_pin 2
#define Rw_pin 1
#define Rs_pin 0
#define D4_pin 4
#define D5_pin 5
#define D6_pin 6
#define D7_pin 7

int in2 = 4;

String Names[] = { "RAVEN", "Surtr", "Tech",}; //Those are the names affected to the fingertemplates IDs
                                                 //The first on which is Names[0] : Yassine has the ID 1 in the fingerprint sensor

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);                  //Fingerprint sensor wiring RX 3, TX 2           
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR,En_pin,Rw_pin,Rs_pin,D4_pin,D5_pin,D6_pin,D7_pin); //LCD declaring

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);                    //Fingerprint sensor declaring

int coinCount = 0;
int coinSlotSignal;
int requiredCoins = 1;
boolean coinInserted = false;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  pinMode(coinSlot, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.write(EEPROM.read(5)); 
  
  Serial.begin(9600);               //Serial begin incase you need to see something on the serial monitor
  finger.begin(57600);              //Sensor baude rate
  lcd.begin (16,2);
  lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.home();
  finger.getTemplateCount();        //Counts the number of templates stored in the sensor flash memory
  delay(2000);
}

void loop()                     
{
  int result = getFingerprintIDez();  //This function keeps looping and waiting for a fingerprint to be put on the sensor
    OpenDoor();


  // Coinslot
  while(!coinInserted){
    coinSlotSignal = digitalRead(coinSlot);
    
    if(coinSlotSignal < 1) {
      coinCount += 1;
      coinInserted = true;
      EEPROM.write(0,coinCount);
      Serial.println(EEPROM.read(0)); 
      
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("TOTAL:");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(coinCount);    
    } // if
  } // while
    
  while(coinInserted) {
   coinSlotSignal = digitalRead(coinSlot);
    if(coinSlotSignal >0) {
      coinInserted = false;
    }
  }
  
  if(coinCount >= requiredCoins) {
    delay(1500);
  }
}


//Main function taken from the "fingerprint" example and modified
//Only the modifications are commented
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();        //Image scanning
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1; 

  p = finger.image2Tz();               //Converting
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  lcd.clear();                     //And here we write a message or take an action for the denied template
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();     //Looking for matches in the internal memory
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK){          //if the searching fails it means that the template isn't registered
    lcd.print("Access denied");
    delay(2000);
    return -1;
  }
            //If we found a match we proceed in the function
 
  lcd.print("Welcome");                  //Printing a message for the recognized template
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print(Names[finger.fingerID-1]); //Then print the name we gave it and the -1 is to remove the shift as the ID starts from "1" but the array from "0"
  return finger.fingerID;
}

/*The two following functions depends on your locking system
 *mine has a DC motor that should turn in both ways for opening and closing
 *that's why I'm using H bridge, you could have a solenoid with a transistor
 *then you'll need only opening sequence but controlling the transistor
 *as the closing is spring loaded...
 */


void OpenDoor(){
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW); // turn on motor
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH); // turn off motor
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I tried to test using enroll code it was working then If I try to upload the code it wont work in the serial monitor it sayst fingerprint not found

Comment: I cannot see, where "fingerprint not found" would be printed to Serial. Please explain, where this happens.and did you actually enroll fingerprint with a previous code? Otherwise the sensor cannot recognize any fingerprint.

Comment: hI sir thanks for the reply I already fixed the issue sir , I was having a bad balance on my Brackets , after formally formatting my code I found the issues. Thanks